# push getIntent is null after restore activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to open new Fragment and load some data from intent after push (GCM), but in case when I

1. open app
2. open message fragment
3. push app to background
4. take a push

my app is open, open message fragment, but intent data is null

```
 @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
...
  notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
//                            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
//                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            notificationIntent.putExtra("param", "value");
```

when my Activity is open

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("param") // is null
```

How can I fix it? Please help me figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("param");
```

instead of

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("param")
```

Comment: Where did you write this code? into ONcreate() or onNewIntent()